# CNN accuracy frozen

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

So I am training a CNN network to detect certain features from input images. The structure is as follow:

Input Image -> Conv2D -> Relu -> Dense -> Softmax -> Result

The dataset contains 180 black&white images in 3 classes, with exactly 60 images for each class.

My problem is both validation accuracy and training accuracy does not change after only about 6-7 epochs, as shown in the picture below:

[image]

I tried Googling for a solution but no result so far. At first I thought that my model got overfitted since it does not "learn" anymore and training loss keep decreasing while validation loss does not. Therefore I tried adding learning rate decay, Nesterov momentum, increasing batch size to reduce overfitting, but they did not change things much (well, the overall accuracy did improve from 0.90 to 0.92 though), and my accuracy is stuck at exactly 1.00, 0.88 and 0.87 every time (before it was 1.00, 0.85 and 0.85).

The features I want to recognize are fairly simple and I need to use the results in a control loop so I want to have a light weight model with an accuracy of at least 95% if possible. Do you guys have any idea on what should be done or at least the researching direction to improve this model?

Comment: It looks like you have overfit your data, as you suspected. You can try things like a really high regularization value (weight decay), dropout, but theres only so much you can do with 180 samples

Comment: You might be able to get further with some data augmentation given youre dealing with images to bump up your training sample as well

Comment: @Simon yeah, I will try to take more sample pictures, then flipping them to double the number of samples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your model is over-fitting.  The training loss is near zero (and train accuracy is already at 100%); whereas, the validation loss is much higher than the training loss.  An ideal model will drop the training and validation loss together.  You haven't provided any code; so assuming your model isn't wrong, I would suggest regularization techniques such as dropout, weight-decay (L2), and batch normalization.

Comment: I tried adding weight-decay at the Conv layer, but it worked so well that it was a little scary. This is the new result https://imgur.com/vv2qtdh

Comment: Maybe your dataset is easy to perform well on?  Oh well, glad it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Use Data Augmentation tehcniques is another possible solution to avoid overfitting.
That is, apply some simple image transformations like *horizontal flip*, *verticial flip*, *rotate*, *translate*, etc. [Here](https://towardsdatascience.com/data-augmentation-for-deep-learning-4fe21d1a4eb9) some examples.

That will make your data more varied and when your model is training, it will see more samples of what it need to learn. If you just fetch this with the same images and labels, it will just memorize that and wont be able to perform good results on validation/test data.

Comment: Hi Augusto Maillo and welcome to Stack Overflow.  This is quite a simplistic answer and might not help people much.  What sort of Data Augmentation?  Can you give us a walkthrough of how it might be done?  Things like that.

Comment: Hello! Sorry, i'll try to improve my answer. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Yeah, I did all of that. Also shadows, reflections and other sudden changes in light conditions really messed up the result so I generated some random darker/lighter patches on my pictures and increase/decrease their gamma. This step really bumped up the amount of data I had and made the model much more robust against changes in light conditions. I got the idea from a video but forgot the source and only remember that it was related to Udacity.